# Python Class Pet Program

Tags: python, class

I am working on an assignment for Python Programming 157 at my school. 
I need to write a class called Pet that has the following data attributes:

```
__name (for the name of the pet)
__animal_type (Examples: "Cat", "Dog", and "Hamster" )
__age (for the pet's age)
__height (for the pet's height)
```

It needs to include

```
set_name
get_name
```

I have tried like 4 times and cannot seem to get it right... any clues on getting it started?

```
# The Pet Program.

class PetProgram:
  # The __init__ method accepts an argument for the program
  # and adds it to the __pets attribute.
  def __init__(self, pet):
      self.__pets = pet
  # The name will add to the pet attribute.
  def name(self, name):
      self.__pets = name
  def age(self, age):
      self.__pets = age
  def animal(self, animal):
      self.__pets = animal
  def height(self, height):
      self.__pets = height
  # The pets_return will show you the list.
  def pets_return(self):
      return self.__pets

# The Pet Program.
import petsprogram
def main():
  # Enter the name.
  petname = input('What is the name of the pet: ')
  print 'This will be added to the record.'
  savings.name(petname)
  # Display the list.
  print petsprogram
main()
```

Above is my latest try...no such luck...any help? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You should read up on Object Oriented Programming in Python: http://www.python-course.eu/object_oriented_programming.php

Comment: It would help if you could format your code so that it looks like code. Indent it with four spaces. It's just a big jumbled run on line at the moment...

Comment: Not trying to be mean at all, but I would suggest reading over your notes/reading when this was covered. There are a a few things that will cause unexpected behavior (namely how each of your methods resets the same variable).

Answer (score 4):

A `class` is not a program, a `class` should model a thing, like a pet. Therefore, to start off, you should name your class appropriately.

```
class Pet(object): # Pet derives from the object class, always do this
```

Now I think you want a constructor that takes the name of the pet, and perhaps the type of pet as well, so we'll define that.

```
    def __init__(self, pet_name, pet_type):
        self.pet_name = pet_name
        self.pet_type = pet_type
```

You also need a `get` and `set` for the name:

```
    def get_name(self):
        return self.pet_name

    def set_name(self, pet_name):
        self.pet_name = pet_name
```

To use this class, you instantiate it into an instance of the class:

```
    puppy = Pet('Rover', 'Dog')
    puppy.get_name()  # prints Rover
```

I hope that's enough to get you going. You should read up on OOP in Python as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: +1 - this is probably better/more concise than the notes I mentioned :)

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I have been lost all semester, the teacher is brand new and doesn't really help too much or seem to know to much so I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you using "private" `__attributes`? That doesn't seem warranted.

Second, you're assigning all your properties to the same instance variable:

```
self.__pets = pet
self.__pets = name
self.__pets = age
self.__pets = animal
self.__pets = height
```

You should be using something like

```
def __init__(self, pet, name, age, animal, height):
    self.pet = pet
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.animal = animal
    self.height = height
```

and you should definitely read the [tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) before venturing any further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the __pets binding comes into play. Your initial description doesn't say anything about that. I would not have expected an object that represents a pet, as in, a singular pet, to have an attribute that was a list of pets. I would expect something like:

```
class PetProgram:
    def __init__(self, name ='', age=0, type='Unknown', height=0):
        self.__name = name
        self.__age = age
        self.__animal_type = type
        self.__height = height

     def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

     def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

I'm also not sure where the imports petprogram comes from... is that perchance what your supposed to call your module, and then the instructor has provided that as something you're supposed to run to test it?

(also, what's with all the __under_scores? is this something your teacher is encouraging?)

Comment: Yes, my teacher has something very similar as an example and I couldn't for the life of me figure it out. The (__) and the 'import' were both in the example of what to do...I'm not too sure why.....

Answer (score 0):

How does something like this look?

```
>>> class Pets:
def set_Name(self,name):
    self.name=name
def get_Name(self):
    return self.name
def set_Atype(self,atype):
    self.atype=atype
def get_Atype(self):
    return self.atype
def set_Age(self,age):
    self.age=age
def get_Age(self):
    return self.age
def set_Height(self,height):
    self.height=height
def get_Height(self):
    return self.height
```